# Javascript/Vue async method stopping main thread

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

for a hobby project I'm creating a map on wich characters move along a path.

I generate this path using easystarjs and this works great.

The calculation of the path takes a few seconds to calculate, I want to do this calculation async yet I can't get it to work.

```
<script setup>
  const findPath = async () => {
    console.log("findPath-before");
    calcPath().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
    console.log("findPath-after");
  };

  const calcPath = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Calculate path and resolve on done
              props.easystar.setAcceptableTiles([1, 0]);
        props.easystar.setTileCost(Terrain.Plain, 4);
        if (
            props.party.path ||
            (props.party.pos.x === props.party.destinations[0].x &&
                props.party.pos.y === props.party.destinations[0].y)
        )
            return;
        props.easystar.findPath(
            props.party.pos.x,
            props.party.pos.y,
            props.party.destinations[0].x,
            props.party.destinations[0].y,
            function (path) {
                if (path === null) {
                    alert("Path was not found.");
                } else {
                    props.party.path = {
                        current: 0,
                        data: path,
                    };
                    resolve(true);
                }
            }
        );
        props.easystar.calculate();
    });
  };
</setup>

<template>
  <Button
    @click="findPath"
  >
    <span>Load path</span>
  </Button>
</template>
```

The calcPath function takes about 2/3 seconds and freezes the dom.

I expected that with this code using a `Promise` and `.then` it would not stop code/dom excecution, but it does.

Am I misunderstanding how the Promise class is used?

Comment: Whatever is in that "Calculate path" comment is where the problem can be found, but you didn't post it. If it's ordinary synchronous code that does (for example) a lot of iteration, it runs on the same thread as everything else. The Promise does not create a new asynchronous environment, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy Ah check, I added the code.
"The Promise does not create a new asynchronous environment"
could you help me on my way to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd have to put that code in a web worker. That *will* be a separate thread of execution. You'd start it by passing it a message, then when it sends a message back that would be when you resolve the Promise.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! web workers seem easy enough to implement! :) Otherwise I'll just move the pathfinding to my php.

Thanks for the information (if you post your answer as a answer I'll accept it)